# Clock app freezes

Tags: clock

The app that is responsible for clocks keeps freezing. The lock screen widget, the normal widget, the status bar clock and the clock inside the app itself all occasionally show incorrect time (usualy between 10 minutes and couple hours before current time; not even always the same). Alarms won't work when this happens and lately it has been happening multiple times a day. When the clock gets "unstuck" it just jumps right to the correct time and sometimes freezes again. The internal phone clock probably work fine based on what the other apps show. It started about 3 months ago as once-in-a-week thing and has been happening daily for a month now (so I obviously restarted it many times during that time).

The device is Hammer MyPhone Energy with Android 7.0. and it is not even a full year old.

Comment: The variety of durations where this is noticed is symptomatic of Performance Enhancement apps closing other apps when in the background. Check your system for 'Performance' or 'Battery Saver' to designate your clock app as exempt from closure. Sorry, I don't read Polish, so I can't lead you to the right place in its user manual found [here](https://www.myphone.pl).

Comment: Thanks, I found user manual [here](https://www.myphone.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/HAMMER_Energy_LTE_short_manual_2018-09-17_PL-EN-HU-SK-CZ_R201810.pdf), the english starts on 15th page, but I didn't manage to find any relevant info in there.

Comment: Check whether the automatic time and timezone synchronization are set on the Settings, then try turning off and see if the issue still persists. Also, does the clock freeze until the "seconds" part? The date-time is actually persisted in the system, and all clock-related apps/widgets only retrieve the value from there.  The strange things are the status bar and alarms since they are also usually managed by system, not app. This might indicate there's something wrong at the system level.